# $f:[0,\infty) \to [0,\infty)$ is continuous and $f(0)=0$ then $f$ is bijective

Tags: real-analysis, functions, continuity

Given $f:[0,\infty) \to [0,\infty)$ is continuous and $f(0)=0$. Also having $$|f(x)-f(y)|\geq |x-y|,  \text{  for  } x,y \in [0, \infty)$$ Then $f$ is bijective.
$f$ is injective is clear, that is if $$x \neq y \implies |x-y|>0 \implies f(x) \neq f(y).$$ But how can I show $f$ is surjective.
Please help me to solve this.

Comment: We get that $|f(x)| \geq |x|$, taking $y=0$ in the condition you've given. Hence $f$ gets arbitrarily large. This + the intermediate value theorem and $f(0)=0$ give you what you want.

Comment: Essentially a duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2234286.

Comment: @MathematicsStudent1122: That should be an *answer,* not a comment.

Answer (score 2):

Continuous and injective implies that $f$ is strictly monotonic. Necessarily $f$ is strictly increasing (Why?). Verify by induction that $f(n) \geq n$ for  all $n$. The range of $f$ is an interval (by IVP) and it is unbounded. It contains $0$ so the range must be $[0,\infty)$.

Comment: Why induction? $f(x) \ge x$ follows directly from the given inequality. And where do you need that $f$ is monotonic? –  Compare MathematicsStudent1122's above comment.

Answer (score 1):

(I'm writing this as a community wiki answer because it is essentially what @MathematicsStudent1122 already wrote as a comment, and quite similar to the situation in [Prove that the range of $f$ is all of $\mathbb{R}$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2234286)).

For a given  $x \ge 0$ and $y = 0$ we get that
$$
 f(x) = |f(x) - f(0)| \ge |x - 0| = x \, .
$$
Therefore
$$
 f(0)  \le x \le f(x)
$$
and the intermediate value theorem for continuous functions shows that $f$ attains the value $x$ somewhere in the interval $[0, x]$, i.e. $f$ is surjective.